# Sending data from fragment to activity and parse json

Tags: java, android, json, android-fragments

I am trying to send 'id' from my fragment activity to an activity and parsing json data based on this 'id' field.

I am successfully sending data from fragment to TourDetail activity, but it is not parsing the json based on same 'id'. The code is not reaching second try block as I examined it using toasts.

Although the same activity(TourDetailActivity.java) is working fine when I pass 'id' from some other activity. Say, if I passed 'id' from jsonuseactivity.java, it is received successfully by TourDetailActivity.java and the respective json result is generated and the appropriate result is displayed.

But if the same 'id' is passed from the fragment activity, it is although receiving the 'id' but not generating the json and no required results based on json are being generated.

TourDetailActivity.java

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tour_detail);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String rcvid = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rcvid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tourid", rcvid));

    String response = null;

    // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
    try {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in try block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
                //"http://129.107.187.135/CSE5324/jsonscript.php", // your ip address if using localhost server
                "http://www.futurolicht.com/jsontour.php",  // in case of a remote server
                postParameters);
        String result = response.toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //parse json data
        try {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in 2nd try block", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                tname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tourtitle);
                td = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_day);
                tn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_night);
                tdest = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_tourdetail_dest);
                btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_tourdetail);
                btn.setOnClickListener(this);

                tname.setText(json_data.getString("tour_name"));
                tn.setText(json_data.getString("nights"));
                td.setText(json_data.getString("days"));
                name = json_data.getString("tour_name");
                n = json_data.getString("nights");
                d = json_data.getString("days");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }
    }
```

This is my Fragmentone.java's `onCreate()` method code:

```
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_one, null);
        String fontPath = "fonts/ox.ttf";
        b1 = (Button)root.findViewById(R.id.featured_btn1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String id = "34";
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TourDetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id", id);
                getActivity().startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know what actually happened as above code seems okay to me. Instead of sending data, you can make the variable as `Static` and access that variable in other class like `Fragmentone.id`. This will definitely work.

Also did you try to catch that `id` in `onStart()` instead of `onCreate()` ? It is convenient to check if there are arguments passed to the fragment in startup

Comment: i checked the 'id' is received successfully by Toast.maketext()